# bootstrap javascript data-toggle="button" doesn't work at tablet resolution

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have toggle buttons that seems to go dead when I resize the window to tablet resolution. Hover over doesn't work and clicking does nothing. Happens on latest version of all browsers I tested (IE, chrome and mozilla). It works at all other resolutions. I am using bootstrap twitter css and js 3.2 and jquery 1.11.1 and I have no .js files of my own. The submit button works in all resolutions.

```
   <form name="ProgramsForm" data-name="Signup Form">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg prg-btn" data-toggle="button">
                  buttonlabel
          </button>
      </div>    
      <div class="col-md-12">
          <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg register-btn" type="submit" value="Submit" data-wait="Please wait...">
      </div>
   </form>
```

Comment: Any additional css other than bootstrap?

Comment: font-awesome and a small css file I created. I deleted both and the problem is still there. Just uglier looking :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All columns must be enclosed in a row. I enclosed the columns inside a `<div class="row">` and it works now.

```
   <form name="ProgramsForm" data-name="Signup Form">
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg prg-btn" data-toggle="button">
                  buttonlabel
          </button>
      </div>    
</div>

  <div class="col-md-12">
      <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg register-btn" type="submit" value="Submit" data-wait="Please wait...">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be related to your use of col-sm-3 class.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/macsupport/6fohu1sc/)

```
<form name="ProgramsForm" data-name="Signup Form">
  <div class="col-md-3">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg prg-btn" data-toggle="button">buttonlabel</button>
  </div>    
  <div class="col-md-12">
  <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg register-btn" type="submit" value="Submit" data-wait="Please wait...">
  </div>
</form>
```